# Loading page content into a variable in template

Tags: page-template, get-template-part

On one of my custom templates, I need to do some work with the content before displaying it. Is there a way that I can load this content into a variable rather than just outputting it to the page?

This is what I've tried but it only outputs the page content, it doesn't load it into the variable.

```
$content = get_template_part( 'content', 'page');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use the output buffering to store the printing contents in a variable.

```
function return_get_template_part($slug, $name=null) {

   ob_start();
   get_template_part($slug, $name);    
   $content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();

   return $content;
}
$content = return_get_template_part('content', 'page');
```

This would be most preferable to keep using the [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) right now. An alternative would be to use [locate_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) function but it would compromise the use the default templates.

Check implementation of [get_template_part()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L158) and [locate_template()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/template.php#L462) you would understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a template file, execute the code it contains, and save the results to a variable, you need to use php's output buffering:

```
ob_start();
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```